# Flot Chart area getting smaller at each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plot, flot

I'm using Flot Charts to plot the data and I am facing a strange problem. At each iteration, the plot area gets smaller, in the images attached this can be seen. I will post the function I'm using to plot to make it easier to understand or to locate the error.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
                var xVal = 0;
                var data3 = [[],[]];
                var dataset4=<?php echo json_encode($dataset4); ?>;
                var dataset5=<?php echo json_encode($dataset5); ?>;
                var totallength = dataset4.length;
                var options3 = {
                    };
                var plot = $.plot( $("#placeholder3"), data3, options3);
                var yVal1 = [];
                var yVal2 = [];            
                function getData(){
                    yVal1 = parseFloat(dataset5[xVal]);
                    //yVal2 = parseFloat(dataset5[xVal +1]);
                    var datum1 = [parseFloat(dataset4[xVal]), yVal1];
                    //var datum2 = [parseFloat(dataset4[xVal + 1]), yVal2];
                    data3[0].push(datum1);
                    //data3[1].push(datum2);
                    if(data[0].length>10){
                        data3[0] = data3[0].splice(1);
                        //data3[1] = data3[1].splice(1);
                    }
                    xVal++;
                    plot.setData(data3);
                    plot.setupGrid();
                    if(xVal<=totallength){
                        plot.draw();
                    }
                }
                var plot = $.plot( $("#placeholder3"), data3, options3);
                setInterval(getData, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Maybe the error is at the setupGrid, or at the plot.draw... I just don't know. Thanks for your time in advance!
[image: Start]

[image: End(smaller)]

Comment: There is nothing in the code you show that would explain that behaviour. Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that moving the plot action inside the if statement where I had the plot.draw() solved it. Now the plot area remains stable and plots properly.